# how can I find out what button has been selected

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a piece of code in python which generates buttons dependant on the rooms in a list in my database. I would like the code to return the room name on the button that I have selected and use it to store data in my database for that button

```
class buttongen():
def __init__(self,i,row):
    self.i = i
    self.row = row

    self.roomname = self.row[0]
    roomclicked = self.roomname
    self.btn = Button(screen13, text=self.roomname, command=lambda :print("self.roomname"))
    self.btn.grid(row=i, column=0)
```

Here is the class for each button and below is the code which gets the list of room names and prints them out as buttons. Is there a way I can store the text and use either .cget() or get() to return the name of the room

```
def search():
global screen13
global btn
global roomclicked
screen13 = Tk()
screen13.geometry("300x250")
screen13.title("Rooms")
sitename3_info = sitename.get().strip()
if sitename3_info:
    cursor = cnn.cursor()
    # combine the two SQL statements into one
    sql = ("SELECT roomname FROM rooms, Sites "
           "WHERE rooms.siteID_fk2 = Sites.siteID AND siteName = %s")
    cursor.execute(sql, [sitename3_info])
    rooms = cursor.fetchall()
    # remove previous result (assume screen13 contains only result)
    for w in screen13.winfo_children():
        w.destroy()
    if rooms:
        for i, row in enumerate(rooms):
            buttongen(i, row)
            roomname = row[0]
            roomclicked = roomname
            btn = Button(screen13, text=roomname, command=lambda room=roomname: action(room))
            btn.grid(row=i, column=0)
    else:
        Label(screen13, text="No room found").grid()
```

**EDIT**

this is the block to create the audit

```
def createaudit():
sitename2_info = sitename.get()
print(sitename2_info)
name2_info = name2.get()
print(name2_info)
name3_info = name3.get()
print(name3_info)
# Sql code for writing the data that was written in the regsitering page. 
cursor = cnn.cursor()
# the site query matches the inputted username with the corresponding userID and inserts the userID into userID_fk
siteIDQuery = "SELECT siteID FROM Sites WHERE siteName = %s"
cursor.execute(siteIDQuery, [sitename2_info])
siteID_fetch = cursor.fetchall()
print(siteID_fetch[0][0])
sitequery = "INSERT INTO `audit`(`siteID_fk`, `auditor1`, `auditor2`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
sitequery_vals = (siteID_fetch[0][0], name2_info, name3_info)
cursor.execute(sitequery, sitequery_vals)
# prints how many rows were inserted to make sure values are put into the database
print(cursor.rowcount)
cnn.commit()
if siteID_fetch:
    for i in siteID_fetch:
        search()
        break
else:
    failed2()
```

this is the block to print out the rooms within the site that's going to be audited

```
def search():
    screen13 = Tk()
    screen13.geometry("300x250")
    screen13.title("Rooms")
    sitename3_info = sitename.get().strip()
    if sitename3_info:
        cursor = cnn.cursor()
        # combine the two SQL statements into one
        sql = ("SELECT roomname FROM rooms, Sites "
               "WHERE rooms.siteID_fk2 = Sites.siteID AND siteName = %s")
        cursor.execute(sql, [sitename3_info])
        rooms = cursor.fetchall()
        # remove previous result (assume screen13 contains only result)
        for w in screen13.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()
        if rooms:
            for i, row in enumerate(rooms):
                roomname = row[0]
                btn = Button(screen13, text=roomname, command=lambda room=roomname: action(room))
                btn.grid(row=i, column=0)
        else:
            Label(screen13, text="No room found").grid()
```

This is the block of code where I wish to answer questions for the room and store the answers in my database for it

```
 def action(roomname):
        global screen15
        screen15 = Tk()
        screen15.geometry("300x250")
        screen15.title("Rooms")
        global q1
        global q2
        global q3
        q1 = StringVar()
        q2 = StringVar()
        q3 = StringVar()
        Label(screen15, text = "Please enter details below", bg = "LightSkyBlue1", width = "300", height = "2").pack()
        Label(screen15, text = "").pack()
        Label(screen15, text = "01. Commodes CLEANING").pack()
        q1_entry = Entry(screen15, textvariable = q1)
        q1_entry.pack()
        Label(screen15, text = "02. commodes NURSING").pack()
        q2_entry = Entry(screen15, textvariable = q2)
        q2_entry.pack()
        Label(screen15, text = "03. Bathroom Hoists CLEANING").pack()
        q3_entry = Entry(screen15, textvariable = q3)
        q3_entry.pack()
        Button(screen15, text = "Create an Audit", width = "12", height = "1", command = storescore).pack()
    

def storescore():
    roomname2_info = buttongen(self.roomname).cget()
    print(roomname2_info)
    sitenameInfo = sitename.get()
    # sql to store answer values
    cursor = cnn.cursor()
    siteID_fetch4 = "SELECT siteID FROM Sites WHERE siteName = %s"
    cursor.execute(siteID_fetch4, [sitenameInfo])
    siteID_fetch4 = cursor.fetchall()
    print(siteID_fetch4[0][0])
    roomsFID = "SELECT roomID FROM rooms WHERE siteID_fk2 = %s AND roomname = %s"
    cursor.execute(roomsFID, [(siteID_fetch4[0][0]), (roomname2_info)])
    roomsFID = cursor.fetchall()
    print(roomsFID[0][0])
```

Comment: Are you creating buttons via `buttongen(i, row)` or in `btn = Button(screen13, text=roomname, command=lambda room=roomname: action(room))`? Because you seem to create two buttons on each iteration.

Comment: buttongen(i, row), the buttons are still generated without the class

Comment: Don't generate them twice - that is completely wrong. Just once. Edit your code and see if it helps.

Comment: even if I edit the code to its original where its generated once it still doesn't give me the correct information I need

Comment: Can you post your whole code pls?

Comment: I've created an edit for the whole code for that section

Comment: I have edited the answer! Maybe now it will provide you the solution you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Code below will do the trick perfectly (just adjust it to your needs):

```
import tkinter as tk

def safe_to_sql(number):
    print("Saving room {} into SQL ...".format(number))
    #Save whatever you want

def addButton(window, buttons, room):
    new_button = tk.Button(window, text = "Room:" + room, command = lambda: safe_to_sql(room))
    new_button.pack()

    buttons.append(new_button)

my_buttons = []
rooms = ["Room 1", "Super room 2", "Ever better one"]

window = tk.Tk()

for room in rooms:
    addButton(window, my_buttons, room)

window.mainloop()
```

- We are creating dynamical `buttons`.
- To each button we connect this lambda function: `command = lambda: safe_to_sql(room)`.

Comment: The buttons will be already created within the search function, so when I select the button a question list will appear and I will store the answers based on which button I selected, I'm wondering how I will be able to retrieve the text on the button dependant on the button I selected, each site will have different amounts of rooms.

Comment: Where to you wanna retrieve the text? To your main GUI class for example?

Comment: so when I select for example button with the text 'side room 1' I would like to store the answers to it in my database. but whenever I attempt to retrieve the text it returns the name of the last room in the for loop